# Is there a way to identify vulgar fractions in excel using VBA?

Tags: vba

I need to compare data which contain vulgar fractions against another piece of data in decimals, is there a way to identify if vulgar fractions appears in the cell?
I've searched online but most are dealing with just one or two vulgar fraction so its fine to hardcode, would like to know if theres a way to spot it.

Comment: Compare the 0 dp value to the value, what is this in Excel?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to find fractions, but it would be really useful to show some sample data.  It's not clear if the fractions are by themselves in cells, or if they're part of other text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to spot them.  There's not enough information here to give you anything concrete, but the general outline will be the same.  I will assume that your data is using the common symbol for division, "/".

- Iterate through all your cells and check if "/" appears in a string with the `InStr` function.

That's technically the answer, assuming that the "/" does not appear in your data for any other purpose.

I assume that you want to do something with the fractions that you've found, but that is highly dependant on the form your strings are in.  But again, general outline:

- Parse the relevant data from all other data in the cell.
- Evaluate the vulgar fraction to obtain a numerical piece of data.